# Table doesn't appear right in IE

Tags: php, html, css

I have an html page with css and php. However, The table doesn't appear right in IE. But it appears right in Firefox and Google chrome.

The table appears down in IE.

If i try to change the css of the table and bring the table up, it will disappear in Firefox and chrome.

here is the code:

```
<html>
<body>

<style type="text/css">

.top {
    position:absolute;
    left:0; right:0;
    height: 92px;
}
.left {
    position:absolute;
    left:0; top:92px; bottom: 0;
    width: 178px;
}

.mainmenu {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
     margin-top: 200px;

}


.adduser {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 250px;

}

.logout {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 300px;

}

.admin {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;

}



.top { background: #4169E1; }
.left { background: #4169E1; }

</style>

<div class="top">
TOP
</div>
<div class="left">
LEFT
</div>

<div class="mainmenu">
<a  style='text-decoration:none;'   href= "index.html"><font color="white"> main    menu</font> </a>
</div>

<div class="adduser">
<a  style='text-decoration:none;'   href= "index.html"><font color="white">add  users</font> </a>
</div>

<div class="logout">
<a  style='text-decoration:none;'   href= "index.html"><font color="white">logout</font> </a>
</div>

<div class="admin">

welcome to admin page
</div>
<table  style="margin-top:40px;"   border='1'   align='center'>
<tr>
<br><th>name</th><br/>
<br><th>username</th></br>
<br><th>remote ip</th></br>
<br><th>login</th></br>
<br><th>Edit</th></br>
<br><th>Change Password</th></br>
<br><th>Delete</th></br>
<h4   style="margin-top:-150px;" align='center'> Users Accounts </h4>
</tr>

<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","sqldata","sqldata","accounts");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM uptable");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

echo "
            <tr>
                <td>{$row['name']}</td>
                <td>{$row['username']}</td>
                <td>{$row['ip']}</td>
                <td>{$row['login']}</td>
               <td><a href='edit1.php?username={$row['username']}'>Edit</a></td>
               <td><a href='userpwd.php?username={$row['username']}'>Change</a></td>
               <td><a href='delete5.php?username={$row['username']}'>Delete</a></td>

            </tr>";
                 }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try running your output against an HTML validator and you'll find your answer.

Comment: @NonExistent: please don't use pre-formatted styles (or backticks) for technical names and product names. It is really only for code and console input/output - words like CSS and Firefox are fine just as they are (capitalised appropriately, of course).

Comment: Btw, these sorts of edits [have been discussed here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265580/a-user-seems-to-be-making-a-lot-of-unnecessary-formatting-edits).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't valid HTML:

```
<table  style="margin-top:40px;"   border='1'   align='center'>
  <tr>
    <br><th>name</th><br/>
    <br><th>username</th></br>
    <br><th>remote ip</th></br>
    <br><th>login</th></br>
    <br><th>Edit</th></br>
    <br><th>Change Password</th></br>
    <br><th>Delete</th></br>
    <h4   style="margin-top:-150px;" align='center'> Users Accounts </h4>
  </tr>
```

`<br>` elements can't have contents, it represents a line-break.

The `<h4>` isn't in a `<th>` or `<td>`.

Comment: help me please to fix my code. if you dont mind. i have been sick for a while here.

Comment: @user3818265: can you indicate what specifically you are stuck on? It seems that this answer will fix your problem.